# Renaming multiple columns in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I hope this is not a duplicate question as I could not find an answer I was interested in using. I have 70 columns and I want to rename them. I know several approaches as an example:

```rb
df1<-setmames (df1, c("BA1", "MA2", "NA3"...), c( "AB1","QB2","Q3"...))
```

But these approaches are not helpful as we have a very large scripts. I wonder if we could do it with a small script using `tidyverse`?

Just as an example I can show three columns, assuming I have this table:

```html
AB1 AB2 AB3
12 13 13
12 13 13
12 11 13
12 13 17
12 13 16
```

I want to get this table

```html
MZ1 MZ2 MZ3
12 13 13
12 13 13
12 11 13
12 13 17
12 13 16
```

Considering this is just an example , I have 70 columns.

Comment: Please see the above code.

Comment: I think you meant `setnames` instead of `setmames`.

And I really don't know what you want without a consistent reproducible code.

Comment: I think you should specify what you are really looking for. Several completely correct approaches have been proposed, but apparently not satisfying your needs.

Comment: You haven't spelled out the pattern of how you want to get from your current set of names to your desired ones. What's the logic of BA --> AB but MA --> QB? There are a lot of questions already on SO on batch renaming, but without any type of [mcve] it's hard to either point you to those or give an answer that works. And your code wouldn't run with a sample of data because of the typo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use the index or column names

```
names(df1)[1:70] <- v1
```

where

```
 v1<- c("AB1", "QB2", ...)
```

---

With `dplyr`, we can use `rename_at`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
          rename_at(1:70, ~ v1)
```

If we are renaming columns that starts with `AB'

```
names(df1)
#[1] "x1"  "x2"  "AB1" "AB2"

df1 %>%
   rename_at(vars(matches('^AB\\d+$')), ~ str_replace(., 'AB', 'MZ'))
#  x1 x2        MZ1       MZ2
#1  1  6 -0.5458808 0.6048889
#2  2  7  0.5365853 0.3707349
#3  3  8  0.4196231 0.6716903
#4  4  9 -0.5836272 0.6729823
#5  5 10  0.8474600 0.3204306
```

Or in `base R`

```
i1 <- grep("^AB\\d+$", names(df1))
names(df1)[i1] <- sub("AB", "MZ", names(df1)[i1])
```

#### Update

```
df2 <- df2 %>%
         rename_at(vars(matches("^AB\\d+$")), ~ str_replace(., "AB", "MZ"))
df2
#  MZ1 MZ2 MZ3
#1  12  13  13
#2  12  13  13
#3  12  11  13
#4  12  13  17
#5  12  13  16
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(x1 = 1:5, x2 = 6:10, AB1 = rnorm(5), AB2 = runif(5))
```

original data values

```
df1
#  x1 x2        AB1       AB2
#1  1  6 -0.5458808 0.6048889
#2  2  7  0.5365853 0.3707349
#3  3  8  0.4196231 0.6716903
#4  4  9 -0.5836272 0.6729823
#5  5 10  0.8474600 0.3204306
```

#### Updated data from OP's post

```
df2 <- structure(list(AB1 = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), AB2 = c(13L, 
 13L, 11L, 13L, 13L), AB3 = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 17L, 16L)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208223/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-renaming-multiple-columns-in-r).